# some problems with mongoDB - how to get last row value exist on group condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have some problem with mongo.

I need to get last name of a row if exist.
mongo document

`{
  _id: Object...
  campaign: 1
  total: 1
  ...: .
  ..
  campaignName: "name of campaign"

},
{
  _id: Object...
  campaign: 2
  total:3
  ...: .
  ..
  campaignName: "name of campaign 2"

},
{
  _id: Object...
  campaign: 1
  total: 1
  ...: .
  ..
  campaignName: "z name of campaign"

},
{
  _id: Object...
  campaign: 1
  total: 6
  ...: .
  .. 
}`

how he see the "campaignName"  is missing on tree position of the collection

If i do this:

```js
db.dataweek.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        "campaignName": 1
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: { "$_id", "$campaign" },
        campaignName: {
            $last: "$campaignName"
        },
        total: {
            $sum: "$total"
        }
    }
}])
```

I get the result `ok` if all the last rows its have a field `campaignName`, but if not I get a null name for this field.

My question is how to get the last `campaignName` value which exists ( group campaign ) .

and the result should be like:

`campaign: 1
   total: 8
   ..
   campaignName: "z name of campaign"`

campaign: 2
   total: 3
   ..
   campaignName: "name of campaign 2"

....

you can see the name of campaign 1 has changed

PS. $first is not valid, i need the last campaignName exists but diferrent to ''

Comment: Please, provide an example of how you data looks and of what you want to get from MongoDB as a result of the aggregation?

Comment: If you have one campaign name per document then how will grouping on _id solve your problem? Sounds like you just want: `db.c.find().sort({campaignNBame: -1}).limit(1)`

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell you need to [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) the documents first before grouping so that the expected result is last. Consider the following sample:

```js
{ "a" : 1, "title" : "here" }
{ "a" : 1 }
{ "a" : 1, "title" : "there" }
{ "a" : 2 }
{ "a" : 2, "title" : "here" }
{ "a" : 2, "title" : "there" }
{ "a" : 1 }
{ "a" : 2 }
```

So to find the last valid "title" when grouping by "a" and obtaining the count, first sort by the grouping key and the "title". Entries that do not contain the title will be listed first:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "a": 1, "title": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$a",
        "title": { "$last": "$title" },
        "total": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

Of course the results are sorted on that field so "t" would come after "h" in this example. So if you had another result to "sort" on such as a "date" which was important then you would include that in the sort order first:

```js
{ "$sort": { "a": 1, "date": 1, "title": 1 } }
```

But there really would be no other way to ensure this with [**`$last`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) as you cannot say

> *"Last if the value exists"*

The [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) clause for the query portion would remove entries where this was not present, so that would change the "count" on results. There is a [**`$ifNull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator which evaluates whether the field is present and alternately returns another value, but that really is no use to you without a "sort".

Also note that for a single field where you are not looking for multiple fields or the "last" entry by some other sorted condition, the [**`$max`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) operator does the same thing without having to apply a sort.

Comment: your answer is good, but not for me ..  the campaignName can be change  d..   and i need last value changed != ''  .. see add new document ..